# Problem configuring Flutter "sign_in_with_apple" for android

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication, sign-in-with-apple

I am trying to set up the Flutter [sign_in_with_apple](https://pub.dev/packages/sign_in_with_apple) package but run into problems with the android side.

What I have done so far, following the package README to the letter:

1. Set up the glitch.me server. The server is up and listening at `https://MYSERVER.glitch.me/callbacks/sign_in_with_apple` I've added a bit of console logging to make sure I know when the server is hit.
2. Set up appid and serviceid on the apple developer console. Service identifier is `com.company.foobar.dev.signin`
3. Added the glitch callback https://MYSERVER.glitch.me/callbacks/sign_in_with_apple as the return url on the service configuration.
4. Copied the activity block from the readme into my android manifest. NOTE: I didn't know what to set the name. Leave it referring to the package or change it to my app id? It's currently `android:name="com.aboutyou.dart_packages.sign_in_with_apple.SignInWithAppleCallback"`
5. Add this block to my flutter service:

```
          "https://MYSERVER.glitch.me/callbacks/sign_in_with_apple";
      final appleIdCredential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
          scopes: [
            AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
            AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
          ],
          webAuthenticationOptions: WebAuthenticationOptions(
              clientId: "com.company.foobar.dev.signin",
              redirectUri: Uri.parse(redirectURL)));
```

Unfortunately, the call to `SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential` in step 5 throws an exception and I am seeing invalid_request invalid web redirect url. The glitch server is never even hit, which makes me think that even if I messed up at Step 4 (the intent name in the android manifest) the problem is more likely in the apple developer console setup. However, I am pretty sure I've followed the README and I am running out of ideas.

[image]

Comment: Please check if you have enabled the 'Sign with Apple' capability against the Identifier and configured the necessary setup for the creation of 'Service ID' and configuration for the glitch web app.

Comment: Good points but I did all of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, I threw away the apple developer console service setup for the dev package (with applicationIdSuffix '.dev' and bundleid 'com.company.foobar.dev') and set up the same for the production flavor. This one works as expected.

I am now wondering if apple doesn't even redirect the request to the glitch server for android unless the package has as playstore presence. Comments?

Comment: Playstore presence is not required. I have recently implemented this and received the exact same error when the sign in capability was  not enabled properly or the service id is not configured with the correct web domain and redirect url. The invalid error shows that service id configuration part is not correct. I faced an issue with a redirection uri and deep link part, but yours doesn't seem that way.

Comment: Any idea about apple login on flutter web project ?

Answer (score -1):

when you handle with the tutorial, but you get a wrong result, please try as below:

first, check your server setting about intended info;

second, you need set your phone's default browser to chrome;

after you login with webpage:

if the browser show the invalid_request, it maybe you set wrong redirectUri or your setted redirectUri is different from the serviceId confirm's returnUrl in your apple developer center;

if the brower show 'the page can't be opened because the URL is
invalid. (-302)', it maybe your phone's browser is unsupported callback to app, you need set phone's default browser is chrome to slove.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).